# why in Linux VM like vmware and XenServer, physical id > the number of cores in /proc/cpuinfo

Tags: linux, virtual-machine

This was only observed in Linux virtual machines. In /proc/cpuinfo, the physical id could be very large, exceeding the number of cpus.

For below example, 4 core systems but the physical id is 13. Also had another virtual machine, only 2 cores, but one physical id is 2.

Anyone has idea how virtual machine defines the linux physical ID?

```
processor       : 0
vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
cpu family      : 6
model           : 45
model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2690 0 @ 2.90GHz
stepping        : 7
microcode       : 1808
cpu MHz         : 2900.040
cache size      : 20480 KB
physical id     : 13
siblings        : 1
core id         : 0
cpu cores       : 1
apicid          : 13
initial apicid  : 13
fpu             : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level     : 13
wp              : yes
flags           : fpu de tsc msr pae cx8 sep cmov pat clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht syscall nx lm constant_tsc rep_good unfair_spinlock pni pclmulqdq ssse3 cx16 sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes hypervisor lahf_lm arat epb pln pts dts
bogomips        : 5800.08
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 46 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor       : 1
vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
cpu family      : 6
model           : 45
model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2690 0 @ 2.90GHz
stepping        : 7
microcode       : 1808
cpu MHz         : 2900.040
cache size      : 20480 KB
physical id     : 13
siblings        : 1
core id         : 0
cpu cores       : 1
apicid          : 13
initial apicid  : 13
fpu             : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level     : 13
wp              : yes
flags           : fpu de tsc msr pae cx8 sep cmov pat clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht syscall nx lm constant_tsc rep_good unfair_spinlock pni pclmulqdq ssse3 cx16 sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes hypervisor lahf_lm arat epb pln pts dts
bogomips        : 5800.08
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 46 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor       : 2
vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
cpu family      : 6
model           : 45
model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2690 0 @ 2.90GHz
stepping        : 7
microcode       : 1808
cpu MHz         : 2900.040
cache size      : 20480 KB
physical id     : 13
siblings        : 1
core id         : 0
cpu cores       : 1
apicid          : 13
initial apicid  : 13
fpu             : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level     : 13
wp              : yes
flags           : fpu de tsc msr pae cx8 sep cmov pat clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht syscall nx lm constant_tsc rep_good unfair_spinlock pni pclmulqdq ssse3 cx16 sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes hypervisor lahf_lm arat epb pln pts dts
bogomips        : 5800.08
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 46 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor       : 3
vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
cpu family      : 6
model           : 45
model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2690 0 @ 2.90GHz
stepping        : 7
microcode       : 1808
cpu MHz         : 2900.040
cache size      : 20480 KB
physical id     : 13
siblings        : 1
core id         : 0
cpu cores       : 1
apicid          : 13
initial apicid  : 13
fpu             : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level     : 13
wp              : yes
flags           : fpu de tsc msr pae cx8 sep cmov pat clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht syscall nx lm constant_tsc rep_good unfair_spinlock pni pclmulqdq ssse3 cx16 sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes hypervisor lahf_lm arat epb pln pts dts
bogomips        : 5800.08
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 46 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:
```

Comment: What kind of virtualization software are you using?

Comment: see issues in vmware, also XenServer.

Comment: Probably you should add this info to your question (not everybody reads the comments). About the topic, srry, I fear I can't help here but I think the question is interesting. +1

Comment: Another thing, probably the question is - while being interesting - a bit off topic on stackoverflow. I would try superuser.com. You might get better/quicker answers there.